# How can I get all constructor initializer using Clang-AstMatcher?

Tags: clang

I'm new to `Clang ASTMatcher`. I've read some tutorials and tried to get all c'tor initializations.

### input code

```
Person(char gender) : m_gender(gender)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <= I need to get those codes.
{
    ...
}
```

### -ast-dump output

```
| |-CXXConstructorDecl 0x4678ad0 <line:9:5, col:45> col:5 Person 'void (char)'
| | |-ParmVarDecl 0x4678a10 <col:12, col:17> col:17 used gender 'char'
| | |-CXXCtorInitializer Field 0x4678dd0 'm_gender' 'int'
     ...
```

### Matcher code

```
StatementMatcher CtorInitMatcher =
    clang::ast_matchers::ctorInitializer().bind("ctor_init");

...

class LoopPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback
{
public :
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result)
    {
        if (const clang::Stmt* stmt
            = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::Stmt>("ctor_init"))
        {
            std::cout << "===== found: CXXCtorInit. =====" << std::endl;
            stmt->dump();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }


    }
};
```

### Compile Error Message

I got and error message:

```
ex03.cc:27:60: error: conversion from ‘clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<clang::CXXCtorInitializer>’ to non-scalar type ‘clang::ast_matchers::StatementMatcher {aka clang::ast_matchers::internal::Matcher<clang::Stmt>}’ requested
     clang::ast_matchers::ctorInitializer().bind("ctor_init");
```

Any suggestions would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give clang-query a try. With it you can interactively query a loaded AST and easily try out different matchers.

Anyhow what you want is probably something like:
constructorDecl(forEachConstructorInitializer(ctorInitializer().bind("ctorInitializer")))

```
clang-query> set output diag
clang-query> match constructorDecl(forEachConstructorInitializer(ctorInitializer().bind("ctorInitializer")))

Match #1:
/tmp/test.cpp:3:36: note: "ctorInitializer" binds here
    Person(char gender, int age) : m_gender(gender), m_age(age)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:
/tmp/test.cpp:3:54: note: "ctorInitializer" binds here
    Person(char gender, int age) : m_gender(gender), m_age(age)
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~

2 Matches.
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed there is such a good tool `clang-query` (but failed to compile on my linux)